# Maclaurin series, complex analysis $\frac{1}{(z-2i)^3}$

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

Find the maclaurin series of $f(z)=\frac{1}{(z-2i)^3}$.

The answer was $-\frac{1}{4}\sum ^\infty_{n=0}\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}\frac{z^n}{(2i)^n},|z|<2$.

I used the technique $\frac{1}{1-z/2i}$ and differentiated series to solve it, but I kept getting an extra term $2i$ at the denominator.
How to solve it?

Comment: $\dfrac{1}{z-2i}=\dfrac{1}{-2i}\cdot\dfrac{1}{1-\frac{z}{2i}}=\dfrac{1}{-2i}\sum_{n\geq0}(\dfrac{z}{2i})^n$ now differentiate.

Comment: @MyGlasses That's what I did, and there was an extra $2$ pop up. ($d^2\frac{1}{z-2i}/dz^2=\frac{1}{z-2i}^3*2$), when finding the original series, there had to be an $1/2$ as you have showni, and differentiate made $n=2$, when rising the power, there was an extra $1/(2i)^2$, thus total $1/16$ not $1/8$

Comment: $$\dfrac{1}{(z-2i)^2}=\dfrac{1}{-4}\sum_{k\geq0}(k+1)(\dfrac{z}{2i})^k$$
right?

Comment: right, but it's power $3$ not $2$

Comment: $$\dfrac{-2}{(z-2i)^3}=\dfrac{1}{-8i}\sum_{k\geq0}(k+1)(k+2)(\dfrac{z}{2i})^k$$
right?

Comment: right, so the denominator on the right hand side was $1/16$? but wolframalpha and the answer from the book said it was $1/8$ total

Comment: Now let's see whether our answer is correct or not. Set $z=0$

Comment: So the book was wrong?

Comment: Now set $z=0$ in book answer, Is that correct? Gives us $-\dfrac14$.

Comment: book$-\frac{1}{4}\sum ^\infty_{n=0}\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}\frac{z^n}{(2i)^n}=-\frac{1}{8}\sum ^\infty_{k=0}(n+1)(n+2)(\frac{z}{(2i)})^k$. In our equation, however, the LHS had an extra 2 on the top

Comment: Book surely is wrong, as the first term of series is $-\dfrac{i}{8}\,$:$$\dfrac{1}{(z-2i)^3}=-\dfrac{i}{8}+\cdots$$

Comment: Sorry, my connection dropped!

Comment: Thank you for the help. I really struggled on this one, cause the book was almost never wrong. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{z-a}=-\frac{1}{a}\left(\frac{1}{1-z/a}\right)=-\frac{1}{a}\left(1+\frac{z}{a}+\left(\frac{z}{a}\right)^2+\left(\frac{z}{a}\right)^3+\ldots\right),$$
$$\frac{1}{(z-a)^2}=-\frac{d}{dz}\frac{1}{z-a}=\frac{1}{a}\left(\frac{1}{a}+2\frac{z}{a^2}+3\frac{z^2}{a^3}+\ldots\right),$$
$$\frac{1}{(z-a)^3}=-\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dz}\frac{1}{(z-a)^2}=-\frac{1}{2a}\left(\frac{2}{a^2}+3.2\frac{z}{a^3}+\ldots\right).$$